# Top scroll with var

Tags: jquery, var

the good one looks like this

```
    $(".back-top").hide();
$(function () {
    $('#container').scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.back-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.back-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('.back-top a').click(function () {
        $('#container,#top,body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

but I need a that variable TopScroll or other, because my website is in one page, and I made this:

```
    $(function () {
var TopScroll = false;
        if (TopScroll==true){
            $(".back-top").show();
        } else {
            $(".back-top").hide();
        }
    $('#container').scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.back-top').fadeIn();
            TopScroll = true;
        } else {
            $('.back-top').fadeOut();
            TopScroll = false;
        }
    });
    $('.back-top a').click(function () {
        $('#container,#top,body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        TopScroll = false;
        return false;
    });
});
```

and is not working anymore. I really need help for this one. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to solve with `TopScroll`

Comment: the variable var TopScroll = false; is not changing to true

Comment: i'm using $(".back-top").hide(); for another function, and I need that variable to change it to $(".back-top").show();

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant to say?

```
$(function () {
    var TopScroll = false;
    var updateTopScrollVisibility = function() {
        if (TopScroll) {
            $(".back-top").show();
        } else {
            $(".back-top").hide();
        }
    }
    $('#container').scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.back-top').fadeIn();
            TopScroll = true;
        } else {
            $('.back-top').fadeOut();
            TopScroll = false;
        }
        updateTopScrollVisibility();
    });
    $('.back-top a').click(function () {
        $('#container,#top,body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 400);
        TopScroll = false;
        updateTopScrollVisibility();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I would need more information about your problem. Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to copy your code, save, and add the link to your page in the question.

Comment: Please include relevant HTML and CSS and the rest of your JS.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do this beacause is an entire website http://bogdanerimia.com. If you go to this page you will see what is the problem with the scroll in the scrollable content. If you scroll is working, but if you press the X button, or the music one, and then you go back to the main content, the UP button is not there, even if you scrolled to see it !

Answer (score 0):

Move/Add

```
var TopScroll = false;
var updateTopScrollVisibility = function() {
    if (TopScroll == false) {
        $(".back-top").show();
    } else {
        $(".back-top").hide();
    }
}
```

Right before

```
$(function() {
    var TopScroll = false;
    ...
```

So it is like this

```
var TopScroll = false;
var updateTopScrollVisibility = function() {
    if (TopScroll == false) {
        $(".back-top").show();
    } else {
        $(".back-top").hide();
    }
}
$(function() {
    $('#container').scroll(function() {
...
```

Then add `updateTopScrollVisibility();` as the first line after `if (contentClicked == false) {` and the first line after

```
} else {
    musicOverlay.animate({
        marginRight: -683
        }, 400);
```

Comment: I've fix it with $(".back-top").animate({marginBottom : -35}, 400); and $(".back-top").animate({marginBottom : 0}, 400);